# Можно ли использовать корутины котлина и webclient?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlinx-coroutines

Мне нужно написать асинхронного клиента в spring boot приложение, этот клиент делает 6 запросов прежде, чем я получу нужный мне результат, есть операции где ответ жду около 10-15 с, потом нужно опрашивать по ресту, готов ли ресурс, потом скачивать.
Я стал писать на webclient, но проект на kotlin, и вспомнил, что там есть корутины(никогда их не использовал), стоит ли смешивать корутины и webclient(асинхронного, без блокировки потока) или можно использовать блокировки в корутинах и решит проблему клиента.
А если посоветуете ресурсы, где можно почитать про практики асинхронного, реактивного программирования, то вообще круто.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону Ktor (клиент для асинхронных http запросов): https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html
Сам его еще не применял, но частенько на него натыкаюсь.